# Django and virtualenv - Adding to git repo

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

For may first django app, I used the following process to create app.

```
$ virtualenv --no-site-packages django-env
$ source django-env/bin/activate
(django-env)$ pip install django
(django-env)$ django-admin.py startproject myproject
```

Now I have two folders

```
django-env
myproject
```

Do I need to include `django-env` in git repo (git init), or just myproject. When deploy, how the dependencies are handled.

Comment: I edited your question to reflect that a key piece of the question is virtualenv. Hope you don't mind.

Comment: No, thank you. That would help to reach wider resource. thanks again.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Don't add the env to the repo. Instead, before deploying, run command `pip freeze` and save the output in a text file say [requirements.txt](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/requirements.html). This file should be in the repo. To install dependencies in a fresh virtualenv when deploying:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: And presumably that file (`requirements.txt`) should be in source control?

Comment: but before running the command 'pip install -r requirements.txt', you must first execute something like 'python -m venv env', right?

Answer (score 0):

Bad idea include .env on git, bcs not all apps installed in .env directory, part of this installed in your system directories